# Change add to cart button based on customer group

Tags: customer, addtocart, group

Can anyone explain me how and where I can customize the add to cart button functionality based on the current customer group? I’d like to show a popup or redirect to a CMS page but only for a specific customer group.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Damian

Comment: which magento version ? from where you want to redirct (controller/phtml)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that detail... I’m using version 1.9 and not sure if controller or phtml, which one would you recommend? The only important detail is that every add to cart button must behave the same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check first customer is `logged in` or not, If `logged in` get customer Group. based on group you can Pop Up message.

```
$login = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
if($login)
{
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //Get Customers Group ID

    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    $groupName = $group->getCode();

    if($groupName == 'General'){

    //Here should be Pop up code

    }
}
```

**Edit I:** If you want to redirect to CMS page you can use:

> Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'contacts');

**Edit II :**

If you want to replace add to cart button based on customer group you can edit below file:

> [magento_root]/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

You can put above code in your phtml file where you want to check customer group.

Comment: I understand, but how do I find out which phtml file I need to use? That’s were I’m quite lost.

Comment: please see updated answer

Comment: Welcome @DamianLobalzo :)